# finding the same file in several directories in Python

Tags: python, file, directory

I have a file several times in different directories and I want to find them in my directory structure. The directory tree looks something like this:

[image: directory structure]

the red marked file is what I am searching. It is an xml-file where I want to read out some elements from. The green marked directory is a folder for an equipment-group. The blue marked folder is the equipment itself. Every equipment group has several equipments and every equipment has this file `ExternalswPassThroughSrv.sic` at the same position in the directory structure. So the folder name for the equipment group and the equipment itself changes for every xml file. I never really worked with files and I am new to Python. How could I do this?

I tried it out with just one file by parsing it with minidom like this:

```
mydoc = minidom.parse('ExternalswPassThroughSrv.sic')
```

I also have extracted the elements from the xml so it works like I want. The next step would now be to insert the Path of every xml-file, loop over them and extract the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `os.walk`:

```
import os

rootDir = '.'
fileName = 'ExternalswPassThroughSrv.sic'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.normpath(rootDir)):
    for name in files:
        if name == fileName:
            print('Found file', name, 'in directory', root)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot. I tried it with os.walk too, but much more complicated since the point where I couldn't get to the file directory. Only to the equipment group directories.